# Как исправить баг в галереи fancybox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

после открытия попапа пропадают картинки и не отображаются справа кнопки (зума,слайдшоу и тд)

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 

$('[data-fancybox="gallery"]').fancybox({
  buttons: [
    "slideShow",
    "thumbs",
    "zoom",
    "fullScreen",
  ],
  loop: false,
  arrows: true,
  infobar: false,
  
});

});
```

```css
.doc__item {
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
};
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fancyapps/fancybox@3.5.7/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.css" />

<section class="doc">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="doc__wrap">
                <div class="doc__item" data-fancybox="gallery">
                    <img src="https://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/priroda_kartinki_foto_03.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="doc__item" data-fancybox="gallery">
                    <img src="https://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/priroda_kartinki_foto_03.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
  
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fancyapps/fancybox@3.5.7/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте ссылки:

```js
$('[data-fancybox="gallery"]').fancybox({
  buttons: [
    "slideShow",
    "thumbs",
    "zoom",
    "fullScreen",
  ],
  loop: false,
  arrows: true,
  infobar: false,
  
});
```

```css
.doc__item {
  display: block;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
};
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fancyapps/fancybox@3.5.7/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.css" />

<section class="doc">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="doc__wrap">
                <a href="https://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/priroda_kartinki_foto_03.jpg" class="doc__item" data-fancybox="gallery">
                    <img src="https://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/priroda_kartinki_foto_03.jpg" alt="">
                </a>
                <a href="https://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/priroda_kartinki_foto_03.jpg" class="doc__item" data-fancybox="gallery">
                    <img src="https://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/priroda_kartinki_foto_03.jpg" alt="">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
  
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fancyapps/fancybox@3.5.7/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
```